# MVC application with HTTPS not displaying web pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, ssl, https

I have an asp.net mvc 4 web application. I added `[RequiresHttps]' to my home controller, as I need to secure this site. However when I browse to the home page, I now get "This web page is not available" and the error "Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET".

I have an SSL certificate from Comodo bound to the domain on a dedicated IP.
Please advise.

Comment: Do you try on local or production? Does it work on locally without https?

Comment: It does work locally if I disable HTTPS. I have also enabled SSL in the project properties. It doesn't work locally with HTTPS either.